# Create contingency table from csv in R

Tags: r, ca

I am using `ca` package to perform correspondence analysis. I have used `author` data to perform the analysis, which works perfectly fine.

```
library(ca)
head(author[,1:5])
                               a   b   c   d    e
three daughters (buck)       550 116 147 374 1015
drifters (michener)          515 109 172 311  827
lost world (clark)           590 112 181 265  940
east wind (buck)             557 129 128 343  996
farewell to arms (hemingway) 589  72 129 339  866
sound and fury 7 (faulkner)  541 109 136 228  763

str(author)
 num [1:12, 1:26] 550 515 590 557 589 541 517 592 576 557 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "three daughters (buck)" "drifters (michener)" "lost world (clark)" "east wind (buck)" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:26] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...

ca(author[,1:5])

 Principal inertias (eigenvalues):
           1        2        3        4       
Value      0.008122 0.001307 0.001072 0.000596
Percentage 73.19%   11.78%   9.66%    5.37%   

...
```

Then I tried to write `author` data as csv and read the csv to perform the analysis again. Then `ca` doesn't work. The `str` of the read csv file is different, not contingency table-like. For that reason, `ca` function generates error.

```
author1 <- read.csv("author.csv")
colnames(author1)[1] <- ""
head(author1[,1:5])
                                 a   b   c   d
1       three daughters (buck) 550 116 147 374
2          drifters (michener) 515 109 172 311
3           lost world (clark) 590 112 181 265
4             east wind (buck) 557 129 128 343
5 farewell to arms (hemingway) 589  72 129 339
6  sound and fury 7 (faulkner) 541 109 136 228

str(author1[,1:5])
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  5 variables:
 $  : Factor w/ 12 levels "asia (michener)",..: 12 2 6 3 4 11 10 9 5 8 ...
 $ a: int  550 515 590 557 589 541 517 592 576 557 ...
 $ b: int  116 109 112 129 72 109 96 151 120 97 ...
 $ c: int  147 172 181 128 129 136 127 251 136 145 ...
 $ d: int  374 311 265 343 339 228 356 238 404 354 ...

ca(author1[,1:5])
Error in sum(N) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I am wondering whether there is an easy fix to convert `author1` to source `author`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column of authors is actually the rownames so reading in the csv and changing the first column's name to "" is the problem.

This works.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ca)

head(author[,1:5])

write.csv(author, file="author.csv")
author2 <- read.csv("author.csv")

head(author2[,1:5]) # here to row names are numbers
                             X   a   b   c   d
1       three daughters (buck) 550 116 147 374
2          drifters (michener) 515 109 172 311
3           lost world (clark) 590 112 181 265
4             east wind (buck) 557 129 128 343
5 farewell to arms (hemingway) 589  72 129 339
6  sound and fury 7 (faulkner) 541 109 136 228

# set row names to be first column of the csv
rownames(author2) <- author2$X

# remove the first column
author2 %>% select(-X) -> author2

head(author2[,1:5]) # notice the row names have changed

                               a   b   c   d    e
three daughters (buck)       550 116 147 374 1015
drifters (michener)          515 109 172 311  827
lost world (clark)           590 112 181 265  940
east wind (buck)             557 129 128 343  996
farewell to arms (hemingway) 589  72 129 339  866
sound and fury 7 (faulkner)  541 109 136 228  763
```